# CouchDB log file RIDICULOUSLY HUGE

Tags: couchdb

I've had CouchDB running for 5 days with minimal use. The couch.log file in var/log/couchdb/couch.log is 42GB and filled up my disk. How can I make this moron of a database truncate the log file? Note that this is NOT the transaction journal... it appears to be an access log.

Comment: For now I set the log level to warning. So - the question is - what the heck was it logging since there wasn't even anyone using it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Install [logrotate](https://fedorahosted.org/logrotate/). CouchDB ships with the [predefined config](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/master/etc/logrotate.d/couchdb.tpl.in) for it.
2. If you'll provide some part of this log file that would be more helpful to answer "why so".

Comment: This is running on Windows. Any log-killer you're aware of for Billy's OS?

Comment: @Pugz I'm not a Windows guy to suggest the best, but on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/358172/equivalent-of-logrotate-for-windows) suggests to use [logwot8](https://www.itefix.no/i2/logwot8) - looks good for me.

Answer (score 0):

like [Kxepal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965635/kxepal) already said before, couchdb wrote in there repo also to use logrotate https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/1284